# Dual boot of windows and archlinux with syslinux bootloader

Tags: multi-boot, arch-linux

I have seen many answers to this , however all of them is related to the grub bootloader . Can anybody help me with the basic partitioning of the disk with `gdisk` . I can handle the rest from there .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tipsandtutorials.net/gdisk-a-useful-tool-hard-disk.html) is a small tutorial
Hope it makes it clear enough for you.